# Open GL back faces affecting render of front faces lighting

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I am rendering a model in opengl with lighting but whenever the faces of the model overlap (ie one is behind the other) I get strange effects. I don't think it has anything to do with the normals as I have tried with the GLUTsolidsphere routine and the same problem occurs. I believe it has something to do with my lighting setup. Here is my lighting initialization:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glLineWidth(3);

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

GLfloat light_position[] = {15,5,15,0};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,light_position);

//glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
//glCullFace(GL_BACK);
```

The commented out parts are things that I have tried turning on. I have also tried removing the GL_BLEND but that did not make a difference (I don't think it has anything to do with alphas).

I have looked for a solution online with no luck. I imagine it is probably something simple, thanks for any responses :)

Comment: Do you have a depth buffer, and the depth test enabled?

Comment: Ah, as I said it would probably be something simple. Thanks very much that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

As Reto Koradi pointed out, the problem was that I hadn't enabled depth testing.